# Can Sequelize be used in React native?

Tags: react-native, sequelize.js

Sequelize (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) is an orm that i have used a few times in node.js with sqlite. Is it possible to use it in React Native.

Comment: with what database ..?

Comment: I want to use it with sqlite

Comment: I haven't done it but I see no reason why it wouldn't work. Give it a try.

Comment: @doublesharp that is what I was thinking as well.

Comment: @Ragas, does it work? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, after some reasearch, there is port from the original sequelize lib to one that works with react-native (rn-sequelize).

Check this link for more information about the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sequelize